# How to run Specflow scenario once but generating 2 extent reports for Chrome and Edge

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, automated-tests, specflow, selenium-extent-report

Currently my manager want me to run a specflow scenario test case **once** but can generate 2 extent reports (one for Chrome Driver and one for Edge Driver) without changing the old step definition files.

Examples of my code

The dependency container, creating by this [libs](https://github.com/solidtoken/SpecFlow.DependencyInjection)

```cs
[ScenarioDependencies]
public static IServiceCollection BuildDependencyContainer()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();

    AppConfig.SettingAppConfig(); // it can change Constants.PROJECT_BROWSER to Chrome or Edge from reading appsettings.json

    var driver = DriverInitializer.Initialize(Constants.PROJECT_BROWSER);

    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.WAIT_TIMES_TIMEOUT));

    services.AddScoped<IWebDriver>(provider => driver);

    var projectConfig = new ProjectConfig();

    services.AddSingleton<IProjectConfig>(projectConfig);

    return services;
}
```

The report hooks

```cs
[Binding]
public sealed class ReportHook : ExtentReport
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public ReportHook(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void OnBeforeTestRun()
    {
        ExtentReportInit();
    }

    [AfterTestRun]
    public static void OnAfterTestRun()
    {
        ExtentReportTearDown();
    }

    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void OnBeforeFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
    {
        _feature = _extentReports.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
    }

    [BeforeScenario(Order = 2)]
    public void OnBeforeScenario(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        _scenario = _feature.CreateNode<Scenario>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void OnAfterScenario()
    {
        _driver?.Quit();
    }

    [AfterStep]
    public void OnAfterStep(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        var node = _scenario.CreateNode(scenarioContext);
        if (scenarioContext.TestError == null) return;

        var screenshootPath = CreateScreenshot(_driver, scenarioContext);
        var media = MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshootPath).Build();

        node.Fail(scenarioContext.TestError.Message, media);
    }
}
```

The sample feature

```cs
Feature: YoutubeSearch

Simple demo to test the project

@demo
Scenario: Search Zoetrope in youtube
    Given open the browser
    When enter the youtube url
    Then search for Zoetrope
```

The sample step definitions

```cs
[Binding]
public sealed class YoutubeSearchStepDefinitions
{
    private IWebDriver driver = null!;

    public YoutubeSearchStepDefinitions(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    [When(@"enter the youtube url")]
    public void WhenEnterTheYoutubeUrl()
    {
        driver.Url = "https://www.youtube.com/";
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
    }

    [Then(@"search for Zoetrope")]
    public void ThenSearchForZoetrope()
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@name='search_query']")).SendKeys("Zoetrope");
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@name='search_query']")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

What i want if i run test this scenario once, it should create 2 reports.

One way I can think is force run the scenario test again by using commanding line + edit the appsetting.json before that, but I don't think it is a good idea.

Examples command line:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" "./bin/Debug/net7.0/V5VNTraining.DemoAutoTest.dll" --TestCaseFilter:"V5VNTraining.DemoAutoTest.Features.YoutubeSearch"

**Bonus:**
Just ask my manager again and he said i can edited the feature files but still need to use this [DI](https://github.com/solidtoken/SpecFlow.DependencyInjection).
But the problem if I am using tags from this [libs](https://github.com/totaltest/SpecFlow.Contrib.Variants) or Examples, I can't catch the browser variable in my static method BuildDependencyContainer()

Thanks.

Comment: You have competing requirements: run the scenario once and run the scenario on two different browsers. You can't have both.